# Можно ли лямбда-выражение сделать шаблонным?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, c++14, лямбда-выражение

Есть следующий код:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::vector<vector<uint8_t>> vec(10);
    for (auto& c : vec) c.resize(static_cast<uint8_t>(rand()) / 10);
    for (auto& c : vec) for (auto& b : c) b = rand();
    for (auto& c : vec) {
        for (auto b : c) cout << std::hex <<static_cast<int>(b) << " ";
        cout << endl << ">";
    }
    auto f = [](vector<uint8_t>& vec_1, vector<uint8_t>& vec_2) -> bool {
        return vec_1.size() > vec_2.size();
    };
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), f);
    cout << "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    for (auto& c : vec) {
        for (auto b : c) cout << std::hex << static_cast<int>(b) << " ";
        cout << endl << ">";
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Могу ли я здесь сделать лямбда-выражение `f` шаблонным? Я хочу написать более обобщённый случай выражения, работающий с любыми типами, а не только с `uint8_t`. Если можно, то как это сделать?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Без проблем - напишите

```
auto f = [](auto& vec_1, auto& vec_2) -> bool {
    return vec_1.size() > vec_2.size();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

С C++20 можно явно использовать шаблонные параметры, оставив параметры лямбды векторами:

```cpp
[]<class T>(std::vector<T>& vec_1, std::vector<T>& vec_2) -> bool {
    return vec_1.size() > vec_2.size();
};
```

Comment: уточните, пожалуйста, прямо в тексте ответа (нажав [edit]), каким образом это отвечает на заданный вопрос.